# What is rounding my values in DECIMAL columns?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

I have a SQL update request. I want it to only modify the columns for which a value is supplied in the update model, so I use the general form `myCol = ISNULL(@myParam, myCol)`. Here is the full SQL...

```
update Justif set 
DateTransaction = ISNULL(@dateTransaction,DateTransaction),
Cif = ISNULL(@cif,Cif),
NomFournisseur = ISNULL(@nomFournisseur,NomFournisseur),
MontantHT = ISNULL(@montantHT,MontantHT),
MontantTtc = ISNULL(@montantTtc,MontantTtc),
TauxTva = ISNULL(@tauxTva,TauxTva),
MontantTva = ISNULL(@montantTva,MontantTva),
ReceptionNumber = ISNULL(@receptionNumber,ReceptionNumber),
Locked = IIF(@locked > 0,GETDATE(),null),
Used = IIF(@used is not null, @used, Used),
NatureOcr = ISNULL(@natureOcr, NatureOcr)
where JustifID = @justifId
```

Now, the weirdest thing, at one point the app uses this request just to set the column `Used`.

The `montantTtc` parameter, like all the others, is initialized with `DBNull.Value` (and the SqlDbType set to decimal), then to my great surprise, the decimal columns are rounded to the nearest `int`.

What am I not understanding about `ISNULL()`?

[image]

Comment: The type of the expression is the type of the first parameter. So if `@montantTtc` is `integer`, then `ISNULL(@montantTtc, MontantTtc)` will also be `integer`. Likely this is the cause of the rounding.

Comment: @Ben so I need to do an explicit cast of @montantTtc? When it's DBNull, it's assuming integer?

Comment: How are you calling it? From what language, using what library? The answer depends on that.

Comment: @Ben, vanilla ADO, in C#, using System.Data.SqlClient, against SQL Server 12.

Comment: The `Scale` and `Precision` of your parameter are both `0`. I don't know what ADO.NET does in this case. Normally it "assumes proper defaults" based on the value, but the value is `NULL` -- I wouldn't be surprised if this gets you `DECIMAL(38, 0)` or some such nonsense, which is then used in a conversion in the `IIF`. You can check on the T-SQL side with `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@param, 'Scale')`. Even better would be to actually type the parameter correctly and not leave it up to any inference.

Comment: Should you not maybe use `float` instead of `integer` for that column in the table?

Comment: Note that "null updates" of this form, while convenient, do still cause actual updates to the underlying column, which may have a performance impact. The engine doesn't "optimize out" assignments of the existing value. The fact that you can reuse the same execution plan for all updates mitigates that, but it's still something to consider.

Comment: @Birel the columns are decimal(19,4)

Comment: @JeroenMostert this is something I often want to do, and really want to get right. Is there a better construction?

Comment: Ok, correct me if I'm wrong, you're stating that the column is `decimal(19,4)`, however, is that in your code or in the SQL Table?

Comment: @Birel, that's the table definition. In the code, the parameter is just what you see, SqlDbType is assigned, but scale and precision are left blank.

Comment: The documentation says "You do not need to specify values for the Precision and Scale properties for input parameters, as they can be inferred from the parameter value." This is not the behaviour you want if you are going to use `isnull(@param, field)` because it results in `field` being coerced to the scale of `@param` which may be inappropriate (as in this case).

Comment: @bbsimonbb: as always, It Depends. If it's the case that you often change particular columns, and not any of the others, a dedicated statement/stored procedure that sets only those columns can be better. If using an ORM, dynamically constructing the statement so only the columns modified are present can be better. But a generic statement of the form you use can *also* be better, because it doesn't bloat the plan cache. You want to avoid unnecessarily "updating" columns that are indexed -- this causes unnecessary locking and I/O on those indexes. No need to prematurely optimize, though.

Comment: A test with SQL Profiler suggests that ADO.NET passes a `DECIMAL` parameter that has no assigned precision and scale as `DECIMAL(29, 0)`. That would explain your results. (Why `DECIMAL(29, 0)`? Because `Decimal.MaxValue` has 29 digits.) The solution is to properly set `Scale`, `Precision` and `Length` for all parameters, always, even when passing `NULL`. In other words, avoid generic code that doesn't -- one size does not fit all.

Comment: @JeroenMostert this has been a thrilling discussion thank you. I forgot to mention that the parameter code is generated by [my handy extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bbsimonbb.QueryFirst), so I can now happily code my new knowledge into the extension. New version coming soon. Would you like to put that into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter type inference strikes again. A `Decimal` SQL parameter that's `NULL` is passed as a `DECIMAL(29,0)`. `ISNULL` returns the type of its first parameter, which takes care of the rest. Short code snippet to reproduce/prove this:

```cs
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB")) {
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(@"
        DECLARE @v DECIMAL(4,1) = 123.4; 
        SELECT 
            ISNULL(@p, @v),
            SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(ISNULL(@p, @v), 'Precision'), 
            SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(ISNULL(@p, @v), 'Scale')"
    )) {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p", SqlDbType.Decimal)).Value = DBNull.Value;
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
            reader.Read();
            Console.WriteLine($@"
                Munged value: {reader.GetValue(0)}
                Precision: {reader.GetValue(1)}
                Scale: {reader.GetValue(2)}
            ");
        }
    }
}
```

> Munged value: 123
>   Precision: 29
>   Scale: 0

The *proper* fix is to supply the `Precision` and `Scale` of the parameter according to the column. An alternative is to use

```
COALESCE(@p, @v)
```

which is equivalent to an expression of the form

```
CASE WHEN @p IS NOT NULL THEN @p ELSE @v END
```

Both will apply the rules of `DECIMAL` promotion (which results in a `DECIMAL(30,1)`). Note that this is *possibly unsafe* if the source type has a lot of precision: using `DECLARE @v DECIMAL(17,10) = 123.0123456789` will give a rounded `DECIMAL(38,9)` of `123.012345679`. The only truly general fix is to use the exact type of the column.

Comment: or instead of CASE:  COALESCE(@p, @v)

Comment: @MoeSisko: thanks, added. It's shorter than `CASE` (but still uses the same rules for promotion, which contradicts or at least is not clearly explained by the documentation stating that `COALESCE` "returns the data type of expression with the highest data type precedence").